# Compute $\sqrt{a}$ with Newton's method.

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

> It's possible to compute $\sqrt{a}$, $a>0$, using only addition and
>   division and to compute $1/b$, $b>0$ through addition and
>   multiplication by solving the equations
>
> **i)** $x^2-a=0$
>
> **ii)** $\frac{1}{x}-b=0$
>
> using Newton's method. Write down the iteration formulas. What is a
>   good starting value $x_0?$

The iteration formula is $$x_{k+1}=x_k-\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}, \quad k=1,2,\ldots$$

How do I a choose a good starting value in the case of $f(x)=x^2-a$?

Comment: A good starting value will just be basically any positive number. $a$ itself is a good choice.

Comment: Why? If I choose x_0=$a$, then I get that $x_1=\frac{a+1}{2}.$ I don't see how this is computing $a$?

Comment: Well, you have to iterate a bunch of times before $x_n$ starts getting close to the actual value $\sqrt{a}$.

Comment: What do you mean by "computing" $a$? The numerical value of $a$ is given to you in this problem.

Comment: @Parseval, see here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qdbskhvmjg. The straight line graph is $\frac{x+1}{2}$. Visibly it is quite weak as an approximation but further approximations become systematically better

Comment: @Joppy, if you start with a large $a$, it roughly halves each time until it gets within reasonable distance

Comment: I have taken the liberty of selecting better tags for your question. I have edited the last line of your question. It contained a misunderstanding which the previous answers had been cleared up. I believe the edit improves the value of your question, but feel free to roll it back. Kind regards

Comment: A better starting value can be had by guessing the approximate square root.  In high school (60 years ago) we were required to memorize all of the squares from 1 to 400.  Use this knowledge to get a closer initial estimate.  And the closer you start, the fewer steps you will need to get the required accuracy.   Numerical methods were not taught in those pre-computer times, but if you extend your memory to the squires up to 1024, you will be able to estimate the square roots of numbers from 3 to 10 more accurately.

Answer (score 4):

In the case of finding $\sqrt{a}$, it turns out that any positive $x_0$ will work. However, very large $x_0$ will spend a long time basically just dividing by $2$ over and over again until getting close to the solution, while very small $x_0$ will immediately be sent to very large values and then go through the same issue. You can see this by looking at the Newton formula carefully: if $x_n \ll \sqrt{a}$ then $x_{n+1} \approx \frac{a}{2x_n} \gg \sqrt{a}$. Similarly if $x_n \gg \sqrt{a}$ then $x_{n+1} \approx \frac{x_n}{2} \gg \sqrt{a}$. As a result, Newton's method with a bad initial guess is basically the same as bisection using the bracket $\{ x_0,a/x_0 \}$ (in fact it is slightly worse than that), until a certain level of accuracy is achieved. At that point convergence accelerates.

$x_0=a$ and $x_0=1$ are both decent compromises that take no real work to compute up front, but based on the thinking above, you will still spend around $|\log_2(a)|/2$ time just dividing by $2$ a whole bunch of times with those, which could be a while if $a$ is large or small.

If $a$ is given to you in the form $a=x \cdot 2^n$ with $x \in [1,2)$ and $n$ an integer, then you can "cheat" by taking something like $x_0=2^{n/2}$, which in some sense "does all the divisions by $2$ at once". (To deal with the case where $n$ is odd, you would need to either precompute $\sqrt{2}$ or just pick one way or the other to round.) You could do this in any other base $b$, e.g. $10$, as well. But if you have to compute this $n$ (which is basically the first digit of $\log_b(a)$), then you're spending more time doing that then it would've taken to just do the problem with $x_0=1$.

For $1/b$ you need to be more careful, because not any initial guess will work.

Comment: I don't see why any positive $x_0$ will work. And then you write that in ii), not any initial guess will work. How can I understand and motivate why this is?

Comment: @Parseval For the square root problem, you have that if $x_0<\sqrt{a}$ then $x_1>\sqrt{a}$ and that for every $n$, if $x_n \geq \sqrt{a}$ then $\sqrt{a} \leq x_{n+1} \leq \sqrt{a}$. This means that the square root iteration gives a bounded monotone sequence (possibly excluding $x_0$), so it converges to something, and it is not hard to see that it then has to converge to $\sqrt{a}$.

Comment: @Parseval For the $1/x-b$ problem, the issue is basically that negative numbers are mapped to negative numbers and large positive numbers are mapped to negative numbers. So if your guess starts too big, then you can get sent out to the negative numbers, after which you are stuck there.

Comment: @Parseval The key property facilitating convergence in each of these cases is that if you have an increasing convex function and you start to the right of the solution, or you have a decreasing concave function and you start to the left of the solution, then Newton's method will always undershoot. This creates this monotonicity behavior which prevents anything "wild" from happening.

Comment: It is not crystal clear to me when you working with reals or machine numbers. In particular, the multiplication $x \cdot x$ needed for the computation of $f(x) = x^2 - a$ will overflow for suffficiently large $x$, so the choice of $x_0 = a$ is dangerous for practical applications. 
I do not understand why I can not assume that the exponent $n$ is readily available. I would be grateful if you would add a few words of explanation on this matter. Kind regards

Comment: @CarlChristian 1. You would always algebraically simplify the formula before asking the computer to work with it, giving $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n+a/x_n}{2}$ which is nearly guaranteed to have no overflow concerns (you might have a problem if $a$ itself is already very near the maximum representable number). The same is true for the $1/x-b$ case. Such tricks are quite standard. For example, in my undergraduate numerical analysis class, they taught us how to avoid catastrophic cancellation in the the quadratic formula in the case $4ac \approx 0$.

Comment: @CarlChristian (Cont.) You might argue that the absence of the residual in the formula is a problem, but in fact $x$ and $a/x$ form a bracket for $\sqrt{a}$ so you have a bound on the *backward* error $|x_n-\sqrt{a}|$ of $|x_{n-1}-a/x_{n-1}|$. 2. The availability of $n$ just depends on your given representation. In floating point arithmetic in languages that give you access to the underlying representation, you can just read it off from the data type itself. Some languages may not make it easy to get at this representation, though. In these cases you'll need to do some arithmetic to find $n$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It did not occur to me to do low level operations without direct access to the underlying representation. 
The general case can be reduced to the case of $1 \leq a \leq b^2$, where $b$ is the base. This eliminates the possibility of overflow.
Now $x_{n+1} = x_n - (x_n^2 - a)/(2x_n)$ requires 4 operations (1 FMA, 1 MUL, 1 DIV, 1 SUB), while $x_{n+1} = 0.5 \cdot (x_n + a/x_n)$ requires 3 operations (1 DIV, 1 ADD, 1 MUL). However, computing the backward error estimate $x_n - a/x_n$ requires 1 SUB.

Comment: (Cont.) Your approach can be faster, but the latency of the division will dominate. Moreover, tracking the residual gives us easy access to the *relative* backward error. We have $x_n^2 - a = (x_n - \sqrt{a})(x_n+\sqrt{a}) \approx (x_n - \sqrt{a}) 2 \sqrt{a}$. It follows, that $|x_n^2-a| \leq 2 \tau a$ implies $|x_n - \sqrt{a}| \lesssim \tau \sqrt{a}$. For your approach we can construct an estimate for the relative backward error at the cost of 1 MUL.

Comment: @CarlChristian The problem of finding the square root is sufficiently easy that there's not actually a reason to do live error estimation. In various ways you can reduce the size of the problem; you can ask for $\sqrt{f \cdot 2^r}$ and then multiply it by $2^k$ as in your answer. Or you can work with the "raw" problem by using $x_0=2^{e/2}$ (where $/$ is integer division) as in my answer. Or you can precompute $\sqrt{2}$ and use $2^{e/2}$ where $/$ is now rational division. In any case you can assume without loss of generality that you are accurate to within a factor of $2$ to begin with...

Comment: @CarlChristian (Cont.) which allows you to do estimates like in your answer to obtain a hardcoded number of iterations to use. (By the way, this has been a pleasant little discussion here. I've had some much more combative comment threads before...)

Comment: You need not worry about me. Stackexchange provides source material for my own lecture notes and exercises and allows me access to very diverse group of students. I want to phrase questions and answers in a manner which eliminate errors and misconceptions in the long run. Kind regards

Answer (score 4):

The goal is to compute $\sqrt{a}$ with a small relative error using a small number of iterations.

I will now analyse Newton's method for the equation
$$ f(x) = x^2 - a = 0$$
and explain how to construct an excellent initial guess from scratch. I conclude with some general observations.

Let $$e_n = \sqrt{a} - x_n$$ denote the error and let $$r_n = \frac{e_n}{\sqrt{a}}$$ denote the relative error.

Newton's method takes the form
$$
x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} = x_n - \frac{x_n^2 - a}{2x_n} = \frac{x_n^2 + a}{2x_n} = g(x_n)
$$
where $g : (0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given by
$$
g(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left( x + \frac{a}{x} \right).
$$
Any sensible choice of $x_0$ must satisfy $x_0 > 0$ and it is clear that $x_0 > 0$ implies that $x_n > 0$ for all $n$. We have
$$
e_{n+1} = \sqrt{a} - x_{n+1} = - \frac{x_n^2 - 2 a x_n + a}{2x_n} = - \frac{(x_n - \sqrt{a})^2}{2x_n} = - \frac{e_n^2}{2 x_n}
$$
which implies
$$
r_{n+1} = - \frac{\sqrt{a}}{2 x_n} \frac{r_n^2}{2}.
$$
An elementary analysis reveals that
$$
g(x) \ge \sqrt{a}, \quad x > 0.
$$
It follows that
$$
x_n \ge \sqrt{a}, \quad n \ge 1,
$$
regardless of the choice of $x_0 > 0$. We can therefore assume that $x_n \ge \sqrt{a}$. If necessary, we simply discard $x_0$ and renumber, i.e., $x_n' = x_{n+1}$ for $n \ge 0$. It follows that
$$
|r_{n+1}| \leq \frac{1}{2} r_n^2.
$$
Let $y_n = \frac{1}{2} |r_n|$, then
$$
y_{n+1} \leq y_n^2
$$
By induction on $n$ we discover, that
$$
y_n \leq \left(y_0\right)^{2^n}
$$
or equivalently
$$
|r_n| \leq 2 \left(\frac{|r_0|}{2} \right)^{2^n}.
$$
We conclude that Newton's method converges quadratically, if the initial relative error is less than $2$.

We now turn to the question of constructing a good initial guess. This is not easy for a general $a > 0$. However, the general case can be reduced to the special case of $a \in [1,4)$. To this end, we consider the binary representation of $a > 0$. We have
$$ a = f \cdot 2^m,$$
where $f \in [1,2)$ and $m$ is an integer. Let $m = 2k + r$, where $r \in \{0,1\}$. Then,
$$ \sqrt{a} = (\sqrt{f \cdot 2^r}) 2^k.$$
We conclude that *any* square root can be computed provided that we have the ability to compute the square root of any number in the interval $[1,4]$.

An initial guess can be constructed form the best uniform approximation of the square root on this interval. It is easy to verify that the function $h$ given by
$$
  h(s) = \sqrt{s} - \left(\frac{1}{3} s + \frac{17}{24}\right)
$$
satisfies
  $$
  \forall \: s \in [1,4] \: : \quad  -\frac{1}{24} \leq h(s) \leq \frac{1}{24}.
  $$
The initial guess 
$$ x_0(a) = \frac{1}{3} a + \frac{17}{24} $$
will ensure that the initial residual satisfies
$$ |r_0| \leq \frac{1}{24}. $$
In this case, we find that $n=4$ is the smallest integer such that
$$ |r_n| \leq u, $$
where $u = 2^{-53} \approx 10^{-16}$ is the unit roundoff in IEEE double precision floating point arithmetic.

---

Be wary of the difference between exact and computer arithmetic. In exact arithmetic, Newton's method applied to the equation
$$ f(x) = x^2 - a = 0$$
will converge for *any* initial guess $x_0 > 0$. This is *not* true in floating point arithmetic. The product $x \cdot x$ needed for the computation of $f(x)$  will overflow if $$x > \sqrt{\Omega},$$ where $\Omega$ is the largest representable number. The initial guess must therefore satisfy $$x_0 \leq \sqrt{\Omega}$$ or your implementation will fail immediately. This significantly reduces the choice of $x_0$. In particular, $x_0 = a$ is *not* a good choice for large values of $a$.

It is not irrelevant how you implement Newton's method. The expressions
$$ x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{x_n^2 - a}{2x_n}$$
and
$$ x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n^2 + a}{2x_n}$$
and
$$ x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2} \left( x_n + \frac{a}{x_n} \right)$$
are equivalent in exact arithmetic, but not in floating point arithmetic. Here the first expression is of the preferred form, i.e., a good approximation plus a small correction. It does not matter that $x_n^2 - a$ suffers from catastrophic cancellation when $x_n \approx \sqrt{a}$. If $x_n$ is a good approximation, then you do not need to compute the correction with a tiny relative error. The first expression also has the virtue of utilizing the residual $x_n^2 - a$. This number is often used to determine if the iteration has converged.

---

Even in exact arithmetic it is not true that avoiding points where $f'(x_0) \not = 0$ is sufficient to ensure convergence. An example is the equation $$f(x) = \sin(x) = 0, \quad |x| < \frac{1}{2} \pi.$$
On this interval $f$ has one zero namely $x = 0$ and $f'(x) = \cos(x)$ has no zeros. Newton's method takes the form
$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \tan(x_n).$$
Now if $x_0 = \nu$, where $\nu$ solves the equation
$$ \tan(x) = 2x $$
then 
$$ x_1 = - \nu, \quad x_2 = \nu$$
and we are back where we started. It is easy to verify that $\nu \approx 1.1656$ is one such choice.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use $a$ as a starting value. Newton's algorithm works fine from there. A few iterations, and you will be right on track to finding the square root of $a$.

If you want a "smart" starting valuse, then you can use the fact that square roots basically halve the number of digits. So write $a$ on the form $x\cdot 100^n$, where $1\leq x<100$ and $n$ is an integer. Then you can have as a starting value anything close to $\sqrt x\cdot 10^n$. For instance, $\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor\cdot10^n$. This can of course be done in any base, like binary, in place of base ten if you so wish.

Picking a good initial value can be important. For instance, the [fast inverse square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) was invented to quickly get a good initial value for the function $f(x) = \frac1{\sqrt x}$. It exploited the fact that this was to be done on a computer, on numbers stored as 32-bit floating points, to exploit the exact way comnputers store and interpret numbers in order to get a final result about four times quicker than previous methods (directly computing the square root and inverting it). It consists of basically what I've done here: halving (and flipping the sign of) the exponent, and get an approximation to $1/\sqrt x$ (which they did by subtracting a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))).

Comment: But I don't get this, using startvalue $x_0=a$ leaves me with $x_1=(a+1)/2$. Doing another iteration gives a more and more complicated expression for the following $x_k$. I ultimately have $x_k = [\text{expression with} \ a]$. Wasn't the purpose to solve for $a$ by division and addition?

Comment: @Parseval No, the point was to find $\sqrt{a}$ *given* an arbitrary value of $a$.

Comment: Is multiplication allowed?  If so, more efficient methods are available.  Generally, multiplication is less work than division when working on paper with pencil (and in my case, eraser).

Comment: @richard1941 "It's possible to compute $\sqrt{a}$, $a>0$, using only addition and division" I think that means the answer is "no".

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the point at which $a=x^2$ by root approximation in this method. It doesn't necessarily matter what your $a$ is.
$$x_{k+1}=x_k-\frac{(x_k)^2-a}{2x_k}$$
$$\rightarrow x_{k+1}=\frac{(x_k)^2+a}{2x_k}$$
Inserting a value for $a$ of your choice will cause this iteration to approximate its square root, thereby solving $x^2-a=0$.

I've done loads of work on this iteration,so I can present this to you: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qdbskhvmjg (the first six iterations graphed)

They also solve the following sets of equations.
$$\sqrt{\mu_k}+\sqrt{a+\mu_k}=x_k$$
$$\sqrt{a+\mu_k}=x_{k+1}$$
$$\sqrt{\mu_{k+1}}+\sqrt{a+\mu_{k+1}}=x_{k+1}$$

---

Applying a similar thing to (ii) yields $x_{k+1}=2x_k-b(x_k)^2$, which upon testing with some $b$ values, rapidly accelerates to $-\infty$ for $b>1$, but for $b<1$ it iterates very well.

Comment: You have the wrong iteration for $1/b$, using $1-bx=0$ requires you to perform a division, which is completely missing the point. Using $1/x-b=0$ avoids a division but requires iteration.

Comment: Got it, found the iteration now (I hope) so will update answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't tell us the data type of $a$.

If the floating-point representation is available, it suffices to extract the exponent, let $e$, and use the starting value $2^{\lfloor e/2\rfloor}$. If the exponent is odd, $\sqrt2\,2^{\lfloor e/2\rfloor}$ is even better.

If $a$ is an integer, you can perform successive multiplications of a variable by $4$ and simultaneously of another by $2$, both starting from $1$, until the value $a$ is exceeded. Then $4^k\approx a$ implies $2^k\approx\sqrt a$.

If $a$ is a real number with unspecified representation and is smaller than $1$, perform the above procedure with the powers of $\dfrac14$ and $\dfrac12$.

---

For the inverse, the initial value can be $2^{-e}$. You can also find a $2^{\pm k}$ approximation and turn it to $2^{\mp k}$.

---

It is possible to be a little faster, by using exponential search rather than linear (hence successive squarings). This is useful only when large/small orders of magnitude are expected.

Comment: Knuth has a problem early in his book that warns of the dangers of successive squaring: important digits are blown out of the end of your machine (or off the edge of your sheet of paper).  That problem was about logarithms, but it applies here as well.

Comment: @richard1941: in the case of the square root, this danger is virtually inexistent, because $a$ is representable, and the squarings stop at $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Newton's Method $$x_{k+1}=x_k-\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}, \quad k=1,2,....$$

works fine with an arbitrary initial value $ x_0$  as long as the $f'(x_k)$ stays away from zero.

For example if we want to solve $\sin x =0$ with Newton's method and we are looking for $x=\pi$ we better stay away from $x=\pi/2$ for an initial value. Otherwise we get into a chaotic pattern.

In your case of $ f(x)= x^2-a$ , the initial value could be $a$ itself.

Comment: I have included an example where $f'$ stays away from zero, but Newton's method enters a cycle instead of converging to the only root. I have explained why $x_0 = a$ is a dangerous choice when computing $\sqrt{a}$ using computer arithmetic. Kind regards

Comment: Yes, we can get into cycles with Newton's method as well. The solution must be an attractor to have a good success with Newton's Method.